# jQuery Validation Method (RegEx)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

```
$.validator.addMethod('username', function (value) {
    return [A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+.test(value);
}, 'Username can only contain letters, numbers, underscores and dashes.');
```

I am no good with regular expressions OR jQuery/JavaScript which makes this almost impossible for me.

I simply want to add a method to validate a username to make sure it only has numbers, letters, underscores, and dashes (no spaces, periods, etc) but I can't seem to get it right.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: javascript regular expression literals must be surrounded by `/.../`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here. One, the regex needs delimiters. Two, the regex does not check whether the **whole** string is made up of those letters:

```
var regex = /^[\w-]+$/;
return regex.test(value);
```

I also shortened the regex a bit (the character class is the same).

Answer (score 0):

You want to change your code to:

```
return (value.match(/^[A-Za-z0-9-_]+$/));
```